# Highly concurrent AWS Express Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, state-machine, amazon-kinesis, aws-step-functions

I have a system the receives records from `Kinesis` stream, `Lambda` is consuming the stream and invokes one function per shard, this function takes a batch of records and invokes an `Async Express Step Function` to process each record. The `Step Function` contains a Task relies on a third party. I have the timeout for this task set but this still can cause high number of concurrent step functions to start executing, when the task is taking longer, as the step functions are not completing quickly enough, causing throttling on Lambda executions further down the line.

To mitigate the issue I am thinking of implementing a "Semaphore" for concurrent Express function executions. There isn't too much out there in terms of similar approach, I found [this article](https://hackernoon.com/step-functions-how-to-implement-semaphores-for-state-machines-65e23faeee1e) but the approach of checking how many active executions there are at a time would only work with `Standard Step Function`. If it would work with Express I can imagine I could throw error in the function that receives `Kinesis record` if the arbitrary `Step Function` execution limit is exceeded, causing `Kinesis+Lambda` to retry until capacity is available. But as I am using Express workflow, calling [ListExecutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_ListExecutions.html) is not really an option.

Is there a solution for limiting number of parallel `Async Express Step Function` executions out there or do you see how I could alternatively implement the "Semaphore" approach?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered triggering on step function per lambda invoke and using a `map` state to do the multiple records per batch? The `map` state allows you to limit the number of concurrent executions. This doesn’t address multiple executions of the step function, and could lead to issues with timeouts if you are pushing the boundary of the five minute limits for express functions.

I think if you find that you need to throttle something across partitions you are going to be in a world of complex solutions. One could imagine a two phase commit system of tracking concurrent executions and handling timeouts, but these solutions are often more complicated than they are worth.

Perhaps the solution is to make adjustments downstream to reduce the concurrency there? If you end up with other lambdas being invoked too many times at once you can put SQS in front of them and enable batching as well as manage throttling there. In general you should use something like SQS to trigger lambdas at the point where high concurrency is a problem, and less so at points that feed into it. In other words if your current step functions can handle the high concurrency you should let them, and anything has issues as a result of it should be managed at that point.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. To invoke step function per invoke and use map, without worrying about timeout, could still I think cause the same effect, as too many step functions could be invoked. I can see it could mitigate the issue by limiting concurrency in map but afraid this would hinder execution of smaller batches where there is capacity. I looked further into throttles and they are due to execution burst limit. Retries are out of question as it would affect rest of the system so will have to avoid throttling. Do you have any suggestion for flow control between Kinesis and SM?